# Transforming sentences into questions

Tags: nlp

I am looking for a program, library or web service that can transform a sentence into a question. Linux/OS X/Windows is fine, ideally gratis and open source.

Example: Stack Exchange question title (e.g. "Maximum read speed on a MacBook Pro Mid-2015" -> "What is the maximum read speed I can get on a MacBook Pro Mid-2015?")

Comment: I haven't found any solution so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.